# What is the earliest version of electron that supports Node-API?

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an electron@2.0.16 app that needs `usb`, but running electron-rebuilder I get this error

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild

Error: Native module 'usb' requires Node-API but Electron v2.0.16 does not support Node-API
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/timfish/node-api-version/blob/master/index.js#L43

the earliest is `3.0.0-beta.1`